# Migrating to Drive SDK from DocumentsList API V3

Tags: google-drive-api

I just came to know that [DocumentsList API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) is depricated. So i thought of migrating my app to Drive and saw [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/migration#migrating_from_the_documents_list_api). I mostly use urls like https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/. So is it enough to replace them with new URL's like this https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/ ?

Just wanted to confirm is that all i need to takecare or am I missing anything. My App uses OAuth2 for authorization. Do I need to change anything in there too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are constructing the requests yourself, you have to replace the URLs but also take into account that the responses from the Drive API will be JSON-formatted and not XML-formatted as in the Documents List API.

If instead you are using one of the Google-provided client libraries, you have to start using a newer client library, that you can download from https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads.

The migration guide is mostly a guide that maps methods from the Documents List API into methods of the Drive API and should be used as reference to know what is available and where.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sure will consider the JSON responses. So I have been converting the XML data into JSon and working with that. Now I guess i don't need to do that extra work! Thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

Oauth 2.0 is fine. You can even use the same tokens you already have for Documents List v3.